# No primary or single unique constructor found for int

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jdbc

I have a **model** class like this:

```
Public class Karyawan {
    String name;
    int phoneN;
    Karyawan(String name, int phoneN){
        this.name = name;
        this.phoneN = phoneN;
    }
}
```

I have a html table like this:

| ID | Name | Phone Number | Action |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SP1 | Kyle | 0902040201 | Edit |

I try to edit "Kyle" data by clicking `Edit` action (href). This is the **HTML** for the href `Edit`:

`<a th:href="@{'/edit_karyawan?kode=' + ${karyawan.id}}">Edit</a>`

This is the **controller** for the `Edit` action:

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/edit_karyawan")
    public String showEditPageKaryawan(
        @RequestParam("kode") String kodeKaryawan, 
        Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("edit_karyawan", karyawanJbdcTemplate.searchKaryawan(kodeKaryawan).get(0));
        return "edit";
    }
```

And this is the **JDBCTemplate**:

```
    @Override
    public List<Karyawan> searchKaryawan(String id) {
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM karyawan WHERE kodekaryawan = '" + id + "';";
        return jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new KaryawanMapper());
    }
```

After the data is retrieve based on the ID that passed through the HTML table, the href "Edit" opened `Edit.html`:

```
<form th:action="@{'/edit?kode=' + ${edit_karyawan.id}}" th:object="${edit_karyawan}" method="post">
  <label for="edit_name">Name:</label>
  <input type="text" th:field="*{namaKaryawan}" id="edit_name" name="edit_name"/>
  <label for="edit_phoneN">Phone Number:</label>
  <input type="number" th:field="*{phoneN}" id="edit_phoneN" name="edit_phoneN"/>
  <input type ="submit" value="edit">
</form>
```

The `edit.html` form is successfully populated by `edit_karyawan` model from `showEditPageKaryawan` method. But when i try to edit both the phone number or/and the name field, it gets error:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No primary or single unique constructor found for int] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No primary or single unique constructor found for int
```

This is the **controller** for `/edit` map:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/edit")
    public String editKaryawan(
    @RequestParam("kode") String id,
    @ModelAttribute("edit_name") String name,    
    @ModelAttribute("edit_phoneN") int phoneN
    ) {
        karyawanJbdcTemplate.editKaryawan(id, new Karyawan(name, phoneN);
        return "index";
    }
```

This is the `editKaryawan` method from the JDBC template:

```
    @Override
    public void editKaryawan(String id, Karyawan karyawan) {
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        String sql = "UPDATE karyawan SET name = ?, phoneN = ? WHERE id = ?";
        System.out.println(sql);
    }
```

I try to change the notation from **@ModelAttribute** to **@RequestParam** but instead i get this error:

```
Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required request parameter 'edit_phoneN' for method parameter type int is not present]
```

Or i try something simple like:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/edit")
    public String editKaryawan(
    @ModelAttribute("edit_phoneN") int phoneN
    ) {
        karyawanJbdcTemplate.editKaryawan(phoneN); // in the method, it just printing the phoneN value
        return "index";
    }
```

But i still get the same error (Can't find the constructor). I also try changing the **return statement** to `edit` so instead going back to `index` it stays at the same page after submit button is clicked.

How to fix this? What's the problem here? I'm new in using Sping Boot so i don't know much

Comment: Please note that the data can be **not fully** edited (meaning the user can only change the name or telephone number). I think this might be the reason why the `requested parameter is not present` error appears (or maybe not? Sorry, I don't really understand yet)